# How do I create subdirectories with wildcard names, Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, wildcard

I need to make a few sub directories, but the names need to completely be wildcards.

Ex: `*** ???`

How do I eliminate their special meaning? I thought it was just quotes, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Please edit the question.  Post the command(s) you tried and the output.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can make several directories at once with wildcards in the directory/folder name.

```
$ mkdir "***" "???"
$ ls -ld "***" "???" 
drwx------ 2 me users 2048 Mar 22 08:02 ***
drwx------ 2 me users 2048 Mar 22 08:02 ???
```

By the way, this is **VERY DANGEROUS**.  It may cause you to accidentally type `rm -rf *`.  I refuse to even type that command for fear of recalling it accidentally.  I always specify the name of the directory with `rm`.

Comment: @user2197677, you really need to edit the question with commands you tried and their output.